# ElasticSearch NEST - DeleteByQuery(...) does not work

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I am trying to delete the specific documents from ElasticSearch using DeleteByQuery(..) method but it does not work. The response i get shows 200 status.

I can get the results if i search same query.

Below is my query -

```
 FilterContainer[] container = new FilterContainer[2];
 FilterContainer TypeFilter = new TermFilter
 {
   Field = "TYPE",
   Value = TableName
 };

 FilterContainer BRConnectionIDFilter = new TermFilter
 {
    Field = "BRCONNECTIONID",
    Value = BRConnectionID
 };

 container[0] = TypeFilter;
 container[1] = BRConnectionIDFilter;

 IDeleteResponse response = objElasticNestClient.DeleteByQuery<dynamic>(s => s.Index(ExtractionContext.ElasticSearchIndex).Query(b => b.Filtered(q => q.Query(a => a.MatchAll()).Filter(f => f.Bool(m => m.Must(container))))));

 if (!response.IsValid && response.ConnectionStatus.HttpStatusCode == 200)
 {
      throw new Exception("Delete failed for object " + TableName + ". Error: " + response.ServerError);
 }
```

I have used INDEX as NOT_ANALYZED for all fields.

Can anyone please guide me on this?

Comment: I also added 'type' in the query. But still DELETE does not works

Comment: read this : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-delete-by-query.html?q=delete%20by%20qy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked after replacing query like below -

```
IDeleteResponse response = objElasticNestClient.DeleteByQuery<dynamic>(s => s.Index(ExtractionContext.ElasticSearchIndex).Type(TableName).Query(b => b.Filtered(q => q.Query(a => a.MatchAll()).Filter(f => f.Term("BRCONNECTIONID", BRConnectionID)))));
if (!response.IsValid && response.ConnectionStatus.HttpStatusCode == 200)
{
  throw new Exception("Delete failed for object " + TableName + ". Error: " + response.ServerError);
}
```